# Me sale un error Call to undefined method PDOStatement::store_result()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Este es el error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   PDOStatement::store_result() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\helpProgramming\core\controllers\buscarWController.php:44
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\helpProgramming\index.php(6):
>   include() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\helpProgramming\core\controllers\buscarWController.php
>   on line 44

Aquí esta mi código;

```
 <?php
                   // Instancia de la conexión con los datos requeridos
                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=help_programing', 'root', '');
                $likeparametro= "%$BusquedaGet%";
                $stmt  = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *FROM pageswebsites 
                                      WHERE titulo LIKE ? ORDER BY ID DESC");
                //Ejecutamos la consulta , pasamos el parámetro para el like, 
                //que será una variable que ya se construyó anteriormente
                $stmt->execute([$likeparametro]);
                $stmt->store_result();
                $data = $stmt->fetchAll();//Obtenemos los resultados
                //Iteramos sobre estos resultados.

                if($data->num_rows <= 1){
                    echo 'no hay resultados';
                } else {
                    foreach($data as $row) {
                    ?>
                    <a class="contresult" href="?view=pagew&id=<?php echo $row['viewPage']; ?>&cateinfo=<?php echo $row['categoria']; ?>">
                    <div class="conResult">
                        <div class="titulocon">
                            <h2><?php echo $row['titulo']; ?></h2>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contcon">
                            <p><?php echo $row['content']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                <?php
                }}
                ?>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando no haya resultados me aparezca el echo, pero al hacerlo me da este error, ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: `store_result()` es una función de mysqli, para PDO intenta con `execute() `en su lugar

Comment: Al hacer esto: `$data = $stmt->fetchAll();` ya tienes los datos. Para comprobarlos, ni siquiera necesitas usar `num_rows`. `fetchAll`  devolverá `false` si no hay ninguna fila, de modo que si entra en este bucle: `if ($data){//hay datos}else{//no hay datos}` significa que encontró datos, y si no entra, no encontró datos. Puedes incluso contar la cantidad de filas usando `count($data);` Puedes leer al respecto [la mejor guía de PDO que he visto](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#count) (en inglés)... te ayudará a descubrir que PDO es una novedad con respecto a `MySQLi` y a la vieja API `mysql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios errores en tu código.

### Primer error

Ya lo señaló @DevJoel en su respuesta: `store_result()` es un método propio de la extensión `MySQLi`, que no es para nada necesario en PDO.

### Segundo error

Intentas hacer una comparación sobre `num_rows <= 1`... Si es igual a `1` significa que encontró una fila.

### Tercer error

Estás sub-estimando el método `fetchAll`.

Leamos la documentación sobre este método:

> **`PDOStatement::fetchAll`** — Devuelve un array que contiene todas las filas del conjunto de resultados
>
> **Valores devueltos**
>
> `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` devuelve un array que contiene tadas las
>   filas restantes del conjunto de resultados. El array representa cada
>   fila como un array con valores de las columnas, o como un objeto con
>   propiedades correspondientes a cada nombre de columna. **Es devuelto
>   un array vacío si hay cero resultados que obtener, o `FALSE` en caso
>   de fallo.**
>
> **Usar este método para obtener conjuntos de resultados grandes dará como resultado una fuerte demanda del sistema y, posiblemente, de los
>   recursos de red**. En lugar de recuperar todos los datos y
>   manipularlos en PHP, considérese usar el servidor de bases de datos
>   para manipular los conjuntos de resultados. Por ejemplo, se pueden
>   usar las cláusulas WHERE y ORDER BY en sentencias SQL para restringir
>   el resultado antes de recuperarlos y procesarlos con PHP.
>
> [<sub>`fetchAll` en el Manual de PHP</sub>](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

De lo afirmado en la documentación podemos deducir dos cosas:

1. Usando la misma variable `$data` puedes saber si la consulta arrojó o no resultados. O sea, no necesitas para nada hacer uso de `num_rows`
2. No uses `fetchAll` si esperas en tu consulta muchos resultados. El código no fallará (o sí), pero puede tener consecuencias en el rendimiento.

Asumiendo que no esperas millones de resultados (o varias decenas de miles) en tu consulta, tu código podría ser optimizado de esta forma:

```
 <?php
                   // Instancia de la conexión con los datos requeridos
                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=help_programing', 'root', '');
                $likeparametro= "%$BusquedaGet%";
                $stmt  = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pageswebsites 
                                      WHERE titulo LIKE ? ORDER BY ID DESC");
                //Ejecutamos la consulta , pasamos el parámetro para el like, 
                //que será una variable que ya se construyó anteriormente
                $stmt->execute([$likeparametro]);
                $data = $stmt->fetchAll();//Obtenemos los resultados
                //Iteramos sobre estos resultados.

                if(!$data){ //Evalúas $data directamente
                    echo 'no hay resultados';
                } else {
                    foreach($data as $row) {
                    ?>
                    <a class="contresult" href="?view=pagew&id=<?php echo $row['viewPage']; ?>&cateinfo=<?php echo $row['categoria']; ?>">
                    <div class="conResult">
                        <div class="titulocon">
                            <h2><?php echo $row['titulo']; ?></h2>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contcon">
                            <p><?php echo $row['content']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                <?php
                }
            }
?>
```

Comment: Se me pasó la condición. `num_rows <= 1` y lo demás. Una respuesta más completa. +1

Answer (score 0):

El error es claro [store_result()](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) no existe en `PDO` ya que no necesario tranferir los resultados de su sentencia, simplemente obtenga los datos como lo está haciendo con `fetchAll`  y trabaje con ellos como desee.

```
$stmt->execute(array($likeparametro));
//$stmt->store_result(); // Eliminar
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```